# Python 3.6: Creating a pivot table summarizing counts of values for multiple columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, python-3.6

I have the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['Agree', 'Disagree', 'Agree', 'Neutral', 'Agree','Neutral'],
               'Y': ['Disagree', 'Neutral', 'Agree', 'Disagree', 'Agree', 'Neutral'], 
               'Z': ['Agree', 'Neutral', 'Neutral', 'Disagree', 'Neutral','Neutral']})
```

I want to create a table summarizing a count of how many 'Agree', 'Neutral' and 'Disagree' there are for each category (column) X, Y and Z.

The output should look like this:

```
df_answer = pd.DataFrame({'Response': ['Agree', 'Neutral', 'Disagree'],
               'X': [3,2,1],
               'Y': [2,2,2], 
               'Z': [1,4,1]})
```

I tried to find an answer to this but cant seem to find one that addresses this in particular.

I would prefer for there to be a separate index but it's also okay if the 'Response' is the index if it makes it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) + `pd.value_counts`:

```
new_df=df.apply(pd.value_counts)
print(new_df)

          X  Y  Z
Agree     3  2  1
Disagree  1  2  1
Neutral   2  2  4
```

We can also do:

```
df2=df.melt()
new_df=pd.crosstab(df2['value'],df2['variable'])
print(new_df)
variable  X  Y  Z
value            
Agree     3  2  1
Disagree  1  2  1
Neutral   2  2  4
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot. So many ways to do this! Really appreciate your time and help :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do this with a pivot_table, but if it helps, this can easily be achieved without:

```
out = pd.DataFrame()
for col in df.columns:
    out = out.append(df[col].value_counts())

out = out.transpose()

            X    Y    Z
Agree     3.0  2.0  1.0
Disagree  1.0  2.0  1.0
Neutral   2.0  2.0  4.0
```

you can also name a 'Response' column based on the index if you want

Comment: Thanks Derek, Works well. And thanks for such a quick response :)

Comment: this gets the solution but it is not a good idea to use loops here

Comment: Agree as for large data sets, it could be computationally heavy. But a great quick fix and basis for populating an empty data frame with more complex (non standard) function and logic.

Comment: Agreed. This not the optimal solution, this is a solution that if works and is not critical then move on